# 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'

Tags: r, ssl-certificate

Hi I'm taking a course in regression, and the data is given to us on the form

```
car <- read.table( "http://www.math.ku.dk/~susanne/carInsurance.txt",   header = TRUE)
```

But whenever I type it in R, I get the response

> Error in file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open the connection to 'http://www.math.ku.dk/~susanne/carInsurance.txt'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> URL 'https://web.math.ku.dk/~susanne/carInsurance.txt': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'

Apparently I seem to be the only one for whom it isn't working. My friends can copy-paste the 'code' and it works fine, while I keep getting this message.

How do I solve the problem? And please, I need an answer for dummies.

I'm using RStudio Version 2023.06.2+561 (2023.06.2+561) and R 4.1.2 GUI 1.77 High Sierra build on a mac (from 2012) with mascOS Catalina version 10.15.7 (19H2026). I use Chrome as standard browser, but tried changing to Safari which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not related to R nor RStudio, more likely there's something wrong with your macOS cretificate handling. What happens if you change `http` to `https` in URL?  like `car <- read.table("https://www.math.ku.dk/~susanne/carInsurance.txt", header = TRUE)`  . And you can always open that URL in your browser, save the file and read a local file instead of a remote URL (  `car <- read.table( "~/location_of_downloaded/carInsurance.txt", header = TRUE) `  )

Comment: using the other link in the error seems to work ... `read.table("http://web.math.ku.dk/~susanne/carInsurance.txt",   header = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but I already tried adding the "s", and using the other link doesn't work either. I know I can download the data, but the problem comes every time there is a categorical variable, because then there are " " around the values, and the I can't get R to calculate anything because I cant say e.g. X2="0" (the 0 doesn't exist) and I cant write X2= ""0"" (because then its an invalid argument)...